# Reset Fedora or Systemd without reinstalling

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

A few days ago, I started experimenting with Startup time. My Fedora 22 used to start at 74 sec (shown by `systemd-analyze`, actual time was even more) I followed some articles and forums and managed to reduce it to just 20 sec. But I also screwed up the system.

Problems:

- I can not find any wifi networks, Lan cable works though.
- The laptop is heating like crazy.

I have tried so far:

- I have `unmask` all the services which I had masked.
- I have reinstalled NetworkManager and NetworkManager-wifi

My boot up time is back to about 68 sec but I still can not find any wifi network. During bootup, It is showing that networkmanager is successful, Network settings are also there, But I still can't find any wifi network.

Additionally, the heating problem hasn't stopped. The laptop gets so heated that I can feel it on the keyboard during entering login password. It is raining in India these days so the weather is not the root of this.

On windows I could have done a restore point and gone back to it. But I couldn't find anything on Linux. I have manually unchanged all the changes I did in Past 2 days when I started experimenting with boot time.

How can I reset Systemd settings and `/var/log/` to its original factory state?

Comment: Have you tried *yum remove package && yum install package*    ?

Comment: Yes.  It is fedora 22 so yum is obsolete, I did `sudo dnf reinstall NetworkManager NetworkManager-wifi.

Comment: please post the output of *lspci -vnn | grep -i net* and *lshw -C network* . If you do not have *lshw* you can install it from repos.

Comment: That's an awful long boot time. What is the hardware?

Comment: @mattdm Lenovo Y50, intel i7 2.8-3.4ghz 8gb ram, 2gb intle Graphic and a 4gb Nvidia Graphic (Nvidia graphic is not detected by fedora, I don't know why).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I installed cockpit and from there I found that wpa_supplicant.service was not properly unmasked (not sure of the reason). I unmasked it again (using root user instead of sudo) And the problem is now solved. I really love cockpit now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkManager service also relies on wpa_supplicant for wifi discovery. 
a GUI systemd manager is really useful. Cockpit is my recommendation for fedora.